# Check if input includes two integers and a char

Tags: c

My input is `scanf("%d %c %d", &num1, &ch, &num2);` and I want to check if the user entered an integer, and then a char, and then an integer again. I am doing this: `i=scanf("%d %c %d", &num1, &ch, &num2);` and then check if `i` is greater than or equal to 2. But this isn't always working (for example for the input `1-M2`)... What is a correct way to check that?

Comment: The input is always a string. What you interpret it as is a whole different matter.

Comment: yes... so what is a way to check the input like i want to?

Comment: `i` should be exactly `3`.

Comment: A slightly better choice would be to read a line with `fgets` and then parse the line with `sscanf`. If the return value from `sscanf` is 3, then the line contained a number, character, and number (and might have had other stuff after that). If the return value is less than 3, then the input was invalid, and you can try again.

Answer (score 0):

`i` should be exactly `3`.
                    – Weather Vane